# Univention - Samba - ERROR - exceptions.TypeError - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, domain, samba4

I'm configuring `Univention` `UCS 4.2`

I did a normal installation, installing the following `UCS` applications:

- Active Directory Connection
- Active Directory Takeover
- Active Directory-compatible Domain Controller
- DHCP server
- Print server (CUPS)

When I run the following command:

```
# samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck
```

I get the following output:

```
ERROR(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>): uncaught exception - (2, 'No such file or directory')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 176, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/ntacl.py", line 270, in run
    lp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1732, in checksysvolacl
    fsacl = getntacl(lp, dir_path, direct_db_access=direct_db_access, service=SYSVOL_SERVICE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 81, in getntacl
    xattr.XATTR_NTACL_NAME)
```

Then, I checked inside the file and line:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 81
```

where I found the following line:

```
attribute = samba.xattr_native.wrap_getxattr(file, xattr.XATTR_NTACL_NAME)
```

Then, just before that line I added the following line (for debug purposes):

```
print ">>>>>>>>>> " + file
```

and when running again:

```
# samba-tool ntacl sysvolcheck
```

I get the following output:

```
>>>>>>>>>> /var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydomain.intranet
ERROR(<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>): uncaught exception - (2, 'No such file or directory')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/__init__.py", line 176, in _run
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/ntacl.py", line 270, in run
    lp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 1732, in checksysvolacl
    fsacl = getntacl(lp, dir_path, direct_db_access=direct_db_access, service=SYSVOL_SERVICE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/ntacls.py", line 83, in getntacl
    xattr.XATTR_NTACL_NAME)
```

But the file (actually a directory):

```
/var/lib/samba/sysvol/mydomain.intranet
```

doesn't exist.

The directory that exists is:

```
/var/lib/samba/sysvol/MYDOMAIN.intranet
```

Actually, the domain I specified during installation was:

```
MYDOMAIN.intranet
```

So, I don't understand why inside the python code it is asking for the directory with: `mydomain.intranet` in lower case.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed with Erratum 166, could you please check your Version:

```
root@ucs:~# lsb_release -sr
```

In case your Errata level is lower please update your environment

```
root@ucs:~# screen univention-upgrade --ignoressh
```

Errata Updates comes with package updates:

```
root@ucs:~# univention-upgrade

Starting univention-upgrade. Current UCS version is 4.2-2 errata149

Checking for local repository:                          none
Checking for package updates:                           found

The following packages will be installed:
[...]
Do you want to continue [Y|n]?
```

Kind Regards